# Why use curses.ascii.islower?

Tags: python, python-curses

I've just recently stumbled upon [curses.ascii.islower()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.ascii.html#curses.ascii.islower). It checks if the passed character is lower case.
What is the benefit in using this function as opposed to [str.islower()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower)? Yes, it requires a conversion of a ASCII character to string object, which adds overhead. But other than that are there any advantages?

One disadvantage I found is the need for extra library, which may or may not be available.

Comment: Let's leave this one open.  I don't think it's too broad.  OP is asking why the module exists considering that some functions seem to be well covered elsewhere.  I think that's a question that can be answered succinctly.

Comment: `ascii.islower` works explicitly on ascii. presumably this could be more efficient than `str.islower`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timing both it seems `str.islower` is a lot more efficient so it is not just the overhead of needing to import:

Python2:

```
In [68]: timeit islower("f")
1000000 loops, best of 3: 641 ns per loop

In [69]: timeit "f".islower()
10000000 loops, best of 3: 50.5 ns per loop
```

python3

```
In [2]: timeit "f".islower()
10000000 loops, best of 3: 58.7 ns per loop

In [3]: timeit islower("f")
1000000 loops, best of 3: 801 ns per loop
```

One difference/advantage is you don't actually have to cast to a str object, you can pass either a one character string or an integer.

```
In [38]: ascii.islower(97)
Out[38]: True
```

But using chr with `str.lower` is still more efficient:

```
In [51]: timeit ascii.islower(122)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 583 ns per loop

In [52]: timeit chr(122).islower()
10000000 loops, best of 3: 122 ns per loop
```

The only reference the [curses howto documentation](http://python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto/curses.html) makes about the use of  `curses.ascii` is how it may be useful when using the  `curses` library:

```
while 1:
    c = stdscr.getch()
    if c == ord('p'):
        PrintDocument()
    elif c == ord('q'):
        break  # Exit the while()
    elif c == curses.KEY_HOME:
        x = y = 0
```

***The curses.ascii module supplies ASCII class membership functions that take either integer or 1-character-string arguments; these may be useful in writing more readable tests for your command interpreters. It also supplies conversion functions that take either integer or 1-character-string arguments and return the same type.***

I think you will be hard pressed to find any advantage  using `ascii.islower` over `str.islower` outside of anything related to the curses module.

Comment: Don't think `ascii.islower("f")` vs `"f".islower()` is testing the speed of the functions (alone), since the first includes an attribute lookup.

Comment: @ideasman42, as you can see there is literally zero difference, a few nanoseconds

Answer (score 0):

Ran some slightly different tests, attempting to check only the function speed (no attribute lookups or differences in namespace).

Tested in Python3.4 (can easily run these yourself)

```
python3 -m timeit -s "f = str.islower" \
       "f('A')"
```

`0.171 usec per loop`

---

Compared with:

```
python3 -m timeit \
       -s "import curses.ascii; f = curses.ascii.islower; del curses" \
       "f('A')"
```

`0.722 usec per loop`

---

In practice you wouldn't call like this.